# Why is the magnetic field due to a dipole at equatorial position opposite to the magnetic moment?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-moment, dipole

I understand that the direction of the magnetic field lines at the equatorial plane is opposite to the direction of the magnetic moment by definition. Is there a reason of physical significance as to why that is the case?